# Unable to get bot to initiate a dialog with the user at a particular point in the conversation, using 'Event' or 'FollowupEvent'. What's the solution?

Tags: python, webhooks, chatbot, dialogflow-es

There is a defined conversation flow for my agent. Using some metric, at a certain point within that conversation flow, the agent is supposed to prompt something to the user, the user hasn't said anything, the bot isn't reacting, it is initiating letting something know to the user at this point of time.

So from my web search and previous dialogflow forum discussions, 'Events' seemed to be the tool to be able to do this. So I have a Python Django-based web server which takes in and responds to webhooks from my Dialogflow agent. ANd my chatbot interface is an Android app which I made based on the 'Dialogflow-android-client' sample app present in Dialogflow's github account (https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client). With this setup the basic conversation chatbot is working well. Now I am trying to implement the scenario described in the paragraph above.

Now, to do this I implemented sending a POST /query Request to the Dialogflow agent to invoke an event (as given in the Dialogflow documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#invoking_event_from_webhook). It is successfully invoking the intent which has that particular event associated with it. On the invocation of that intent using EVENT webhook, I get back a json response from the agent back to my server in the format described in the documentation. But the client end (neither the Android app nor the Dialogflow developer dialog check console) is showing the text or speaking out the Output text that the event triggered intent. I am only getting all JSON info at my server, nothing is going to the client app. Why is this? In previous Dialogflow forum discussions, one experienced person said that with Event triggering through webhook, you only get information back to where you initiated the trigger from and nowhere else.Is that true? At that same place it was said the best way to get the response at the client app for the event trigger is to use FollowupEvent tool instead.

So that's what I am doing, in the webhook response from my server for 1 intent that was activated by something the user said, I am including the FollowupEvent info in the response JSON. But still no response from the event triggered intent comes at the client app. I think in this case the intent to be triggered is not getting triggered only, since if it was triggered, a POST webhook request for that intent would have come to the server, which it has not. Why is it not working? What is the resolution?

Here is the JSON being sent to the Dialogflow agent from my server (using FollowupEvent):

```
{
    "contextOut": [],
    "speech": " ",
    "displayText": " ",
    "source": "PSVA-server",
    "followupEvent": {
        "event": {
            "name": "testr",
            "data": {}
        }
    }
}
```

In my Dialogflow agent, I have created an intent which doesn't have any user_says

example in it, has one event "testr" named in it, has an answer text and 'webhook'

option checked in fulfillment.

And finally is there any better method to implement what I am trying to implement?